# Harvesting in logistic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logistic-regression

So the question is:

> Analyze the equation depending on c :
>   $$y'=y(a-by)-c.$$
>   When does the population die out in time?

**My attemp for solution**

So to draw phase portrait we need to find first the zeros of the equation(stationary points), so lets do that.

$$ya-by^2 - c=0 \Rightarrow by^2-ay+c =0 \Rightarrow D = a^2-4bc$$

Hence our roots looks as follows :

$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}{2b}.$$

Now we need to analyze the solutions.

**Question**
However i do not know how to proceed from now, do we know anything about a,b? And should we analyze the case when $\sqrt{a^2-4bc} > a$ and $<a$? Or how should the answers vary?

Answer (score 2):

We need to consider all the possible cases.

For example for $a,b,c>0$ and $a^2-4bc\ge 0$ we have

- $\lambda_{1} = \frac{a - \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}{2b}>0$
- $\lambda_{2} = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}{2b}>\lambda_{1}$

with

- $y'=-by^2+ya-c<0$ for $y(0)<\lambda_1$

thus in this case the population dies out in time when $y(0)<\lambda_1$.

Comment: Thanks, i have a quaestion, how did you know that we need to analize only the positive cases?

Comment: @MariyaKav We can also analize all possible cases but they are a lot if we don't have any limitation. In any case we can assume $c>0$ for the harvesting but then we should consider the cases $b>0$ and $b<0$ and for each one $a>0$ and $a<0$. The cases become even more if we need also to consider the values $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: @MariyaKav Once we have fixed $a,b,c$ the analysis is simple. Do you have any limitation on thise values?

Comment: No there are no limitations in an exercise, it is only written that analize depending on conctrant c.. So then we can assume that a,b are positive and analize when c is negative or positive?? Or?

Comment: @MariyaKav As you can see in the fisrt example of the link given in the comment, the solution is obtained assuming $a,b,c>0$, thus I think that it is a reasonable assumption.